# My ajax url can't work on laravel 5.4 , there is no error show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Contact form for mail send:- Can't pass data through the routes url. The mail send doesn't work. Its a toggle form. So, i can catch all data by using ajax but the ajax url can't work that's why i can't get all data. When i click submit button nothing to happen in my code. no errors no output. totally blank results.

Jquery code:- **"url: '/html-form'"** Not working. This url can't go the routes url. it print the data variable but can't go the set url.

Routes:- This routes are not working? it doesn't print the Hello Text.Cause the Ajax url not working.

```
    
        Contact Us
```

`<div id="contact_form">
        {!! Form::open(['method'=>'post','class' =>'form-horizontal']) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('name','Your Name:') !!}--}}
            {!! Form::text('name', null,
                array('id'=>'name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your Name *')) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('query','Query Topic:') !!}--}}

            {!! Form::text('query',null,['id'=>'query','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Query Topic'])!!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('query','Query Topic:') !!}--}}

            {!! Form::email('email',null,['id'=>'email','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your email'])!!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('query','Query Topic:') !!}--}}

            {!! Form::text('phone_number',null,['id'=>'phone_number','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your phone number *'])!!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('query','Query Topic:') !!}--}}

            {!! Form::text('address',null,['id'=>'address','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your Address'])!!}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{--{!! Form::label('message','Your Message:') !!}--}}
            {!! Form::textarea('message',null,['id'=>'message','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Message','rows'=>8]) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group button">
            {!! Form::button('SEND',['id'=>'submit'])!!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
</pre>

<pre>


$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            var data= {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                query: $("#query").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                phone_number: $("#phone_number").val(),
                address: $("#address").val(),
                message: $("#message").val()
            };
         console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/html-form',
                type: 'get',
                data: {data: data},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</pre>


<pre>
Route::get('/html-form',function (){
    json_encode("Hello");
});
</pre>`

Comment: you can check error from chrome => developer tools => network its most likel a CSRF token issue

Comment: ```return json_encode("Hello");```